# Does not work view function in middleware on laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have middelware like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Request::segment(1)=='test'){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
       return view  ('login')->with(['flag'=>1]);
     }
}
```

and `return view ('dashboard');` Dose not show login page and
Show me this error

> FatalErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 101:
>   Call to a member function setCookie() on a non-object

Phpstorme highlight view and tooltip have this message

> undefined function view more...(ctrl+f1)

When I use this command

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

It redirect to login page, but I want pass flag to login page

Comment: Try removing the gap between `view` and `('login')->with(['flag'=>1]);`. That should work fine with the gap removed, so make the line `return view('login')->with(['flag'=>1]);` and then test it on your local server.

Comment: I remove gap but deont work

Comment: Do you get an error running this on your server? If you do what does it say? Do you have `APP_DEBUG` set to true in your `.env`. You need to be specific when you say it doesn't work - what actually happens?

Comment: What does it mean "does not work?" Please describe actual and expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass flag to login page. you can try this one :

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login')->with('flag','1');
```

Comment: this code create session .I do not want use session

Answer (score 1):

try to put `{!! csrf_field() !!}` in your form like this :

```
...
{!! csrf_field() !!}                
<div class="form-group">                   
<label>Name</label>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for solution for similar kind of problem.

My intention was to return login page view (but not redirect to login page) when user trying to access some authenticated url (say http://localhost/my-site/admin/user/profile) from Middleware.

Following code snippet has solve my problem

Add this to your namespaces

`use Illuminate\Http\Response;`

and use the following return statement in the handle method of Middleware

`return new Response(view('user/login'));`